# Indent, pretty-print code including Django template tags, HTML, CSS, and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, django-templates, indentation

In dealing with a bunch of crufty Django template files, I want to indent them.

The files contain:

- HTML, the bulk of the file.  Maybe a *pre* tag or two.
- JavaScript, inside *script* tags.
- CSS inside the *style* tags
- Django template directives inside *{% ... %}* pairs.

Surely there is a tool to do this.  Most of the tools do silly things when facing unexpected characters.   Which one works?

To clarify, what properly indents this code?

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% if admin %}
<style type="text/css">
body {
  color: purple;
  background-color: #d8da3d }
</style>
<p><b>ADMIN SCREEN</b></p>
{% endif %}
<script>
set_active_tab("Welcome");
if (first_time()) { turn_on_highlights(); }
</script>
<table><tr><td>a</td></tr><tr><td>b</td></tr></table>
```

I've tried various tools, including the Universal Indent GUI, without success.

Comment: ::Shrieks and runs the other way::

Comment: Did you ever find any good solution?

Comment: any solution? what about modifying a sumblime text package?

Answer (score 3):

Try http://prettydiff.com/?m=beautify

See if that gets what you want.  If you specifically need to address HTML tags that do not have a closing pair, such as `<br>`, then add the `&html` attribute to the address above.  It should do everything you need as per the stated requirements.

Comment: It doesn't handle the django template markup like {% %}

Comment: It *does* handle {% %} markup for me. Easiest way I've found so far to clean up Django templates.

Comment: What is the VScode extension that gives the same result? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify is giving different behavior!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't perfect, but:

1. Install django-vim http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1487
2. Highlight lines in visual mode
3. press '='

Voila!  The power of vim.

Answer (score -1):

If you use Sublime Text I recommend installing a package called `HTML-CSS-JS Prettify`.

You can get the package from PackageControl [Here](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTML-CSS-JS%20Prettify).